# Alfresco 5.1 Javascript debugger error no x11 display variable was set but this program performed an operation which requires

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, alfresco, javascript-debugger

I have installed **Alfresco 5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04** and I have also installed the Javascript repo for script editing. However my challenge is when I want to enable javascript debugger through http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/javascript/debugger I get the following error:

> The Web Script /alfresco/s/api/javascript/debugger has responded with
>   a status of 500 - Internal Error.
>
> 500 Description: An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it
>   from fulfilling the request.     Message: 05230000 Wrapped Exception
>   (with status template): No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this
>   program performed an operation which requires it.
>
> Exception: java.awt.HeadlessException - No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

Please help!!

Comment: Start the JVM in headless mode?

Comment: Hi Gagravarr. How do i do that?

Comment: Just set `java.awt.headless` to true in the usual way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/end-user-discussions/alfresco-share/javascript-debugger-error-09112012-1015

Also, in my experience - and I'm unable to find anything official now - debugging won't work when Alfresco runs as a service.

Comment: I saw that post and i tried to follow it to no avail. Alfreso 5.1 installation does not have this file as highlighted in the forum "/tomcat/scripts/ctl.sh".