# How to enable server-side JavaScript debugger?

Tags: debugging, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I have Alfresco Community v5.2.0 and Alfresco Share v5.2.c that running on Apache Tomcat 7.0 Servlet/JSP Container, installed on CentOS 7.3.

As far as I know, I can use two approach to enable the JavaScript debugging:

- Enable the debugger for every time when server starts;
- Enable the debugger when required.

If I use first approach.

For the repository tier I set the following property in `/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties`:

```
...
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.AlfrescoRhinoScriptDebugger=on
...
```

For the web tier I set the following property in `/tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties`:

```
...
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.web.scripts.AlfrescoScriptDebugger=on
...
```

As a result, I get an exception.

alfresco.log:

```
16:24:57,771 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, passthru1]
16:24:57,933 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, passthru1] complete
16:24:57,933 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, ldap1]
16:24:58,105 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, ldap1] complete
16:24:58,105 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
16:24:58,208 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1] complete
16:25:00,084 DEBUG [com.alvexcore.repo.infavorites.InFavoritesAssociationPolicy] InFavoritesAssociationPolicy online
16:25:00,459 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.TemplateProcessorRegistry] Registered template processor Repository Template Processor for extension ftl
16:25:00,460 INFO  [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptProcessorRegistry] Registered script processor Repository Script Processor for extension js
16:25:00,520 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webscript.org.alfresco.jsdebugger.get' defined in class path resource [alfresco/web-scripts-application-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rhinoScriptDebugger' while setting bean property 'debugger'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rhinoScriptDebugger' defined in class path resource [alfresco/web-scripts-application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.awt.HeadlessException
16:25:01,389 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Stopping 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, passthru1]
16:25:01,389 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Stopped 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, passthru1]
16:25:01,390 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Stopping 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, ldap1]
16:25:01,390 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Stopped 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, ldap1]
16:25:01,390 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Stopping 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
16:25:01,390 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] Stopped 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
16:25:01,394 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webscript.org.alfresco.jsdebugger.get' defined in class path resource [alfresco/web-scripts-application-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rhinoScriptDebugger' while setting bean property 'debugger'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rhinoScriptDebugger' defined in class path resource [alfresco/web-scripts-application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.awt.HeadlessException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rhinoScriptDebugger' defined in class path resource [alfresco/web-scripts-application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.awt.HeadlessException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
-- VISUAL BLOCK --
```

If I use second approach.

For the repository tier, I go through the link `http://...:8080/alfresco/service/api/javascript/debugger` then I see the following:

[image]

I press <kbd>Enable</kbd> and get exception again:

[image]

alfresco.log:

```
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 00300004 Wrapped Exception (with status template): null
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:512)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:464)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:587)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:656)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:428)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:308)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:399)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:210)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.alfresco.module.aosmodule.service.ContextRootFilter.doFilter(ContextRootFilter.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:233)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.SwingGui.<init>(SwingGui.java:149)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptDebugger$AlfrescoGui.<init>(ScriptDebugger.java:165)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptDebugger.activate(ScriptDebugger.java:86)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptDebugger.show(ScriptDebugger.java:104)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.bean.JavascriptDebuggerPost.executeImpl(JavascriptDebuggerPost.java:61)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.executeImpl(DeclarativeWebScript.java:235)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:64)
        ... 37 more
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to enable server-side JavaScript debugger?

Comment: Is your server really headless? I know I've had issues with starting the debugger when Alfresco is installed as a service, but it absolutely always worked when I manually started it.

Comment: Check out my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982859/alfresco-5-1-javascript-debugger-error-no-x11-display-variable-was-set-but-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are running on a server without a windows manager, and you are connected remotely. That's why the log is showing a java.awt.HeadlessException.

The server-side JavaScript debugger works best when you are not working remotely and are instead running the server on your workstation.

You may be able to get it working remotely using the technique Lista suggests.

Comment: Thanks for reading, @AlekseyBykov, I'm glad you found it helpful.